# Using a kvm switch with a wireless keyboard & mouse

Tags: windows-7, macos, usb, kvm-switch

I have a USB KVM switch that I am using with Logitech k350 wireless keyboard and wireless m510 mouse with the unity receiver. I have a windows 7 & a Mac that this is hooked up to.

When I switch to the Mac it just works fine no delay. When I switch to the Windows 7 machine its like I'm plugging in the the dongle in for the first time windows makes the bong you've plugged in a USB stick sound or what ever it does.

Is there a way to make that USB port not do that or just stay on. I'm not sure what the actual term is here.

I'd like it to just work when It goes back to the windows 7 box.

Any Ideas on what this is?